# Strange UIView frame size

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

In my iOS application I have a ViewController with a button and UIView. Below you have a screenshow with layout :

[image: Screenshot from storyboard]

UIView control is aligned by autolayout to it's superview and to button.
I've put some logs in `viewDidLoad` method to check ViewController and UIView sizes :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSLog("VC bounds = \(self.view.bounds)")
    NSLog("Preview bounds = \(self.previewWindow.bounds)")
    NSLog("Preview frame = \(self.previewWindow.frame)")
}
```

This is log results :

```
2014-12-10 14:43:38.354 xxx[523:76131] VC bounds = (0.0,0.0,320.0,568.0)
2014-12-10 14:43:38.354 xxx[523:76131] Preview bounds = (0.0,0.0,600.0,528.0)
2014-12-10 14:43:38.355 xxx[523:76131] Preview frame = (0.0,20.0,600.0,528.0)
```

Why UIView (preview) frame and bounds have larger width than ViewController ??

Greetings, Pawel

Comment: Because views have not been laid out on `-viewDidLoad:`. This will happen just before `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` (the numbers you get are what you can see on the inspector from your screenshot)

Comment: Log them in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Thank you @gabbler :) Sizes are OK in `viewDidAppear`.